# Redirect to default language in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, seo, multilingual

Currently working on a Node.js/Express website where I have two languages setup (EN and FR).
If the user enters www.domain.com (=no language set) I would like it to be redirected to the startpage for the default language - in this case EN, so www.domain.com/en but if the user enters www.domain.com/fr it should load startpage for FR language.

**EDIT:**
How would I correctly do this in my backend, so that the redirect happens asap and correct?

Thank you

Comment: Try to limit yourself to one question to one question (in particular, you should remove the second question as that type of SEO question is largely opinion based and thus off-topic … although it might find a home on the webmasters' stackexchange).

Comment: Okay. But I see it as a subquestion to the main one? But sure, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a redirect, just use the same route handler function for both the root and language specific paths:

```
router.get('/en', handleEnglish);
router.get('/', handleEnglish);
router.get('/fr', handleFrench)
```

---

If you want to go with a redirect to make the URLs explicit, you can do the following:

```
router.get('/en', handleEnglish);
router.get('/fr', handleFrench)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/en');
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to use / at all just /en and /fr so if user enters only with / it should redirect to /en. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: So you want to force /en to appear as part of the URL and take the overhead of a redirect?  What would be the purpose of that, just so the user sees that he is in English mode (which should be obvious in the page content).  I can update the answer if you really need this - it is also fairly trivial.

Comment: So you think I should consider / to be english and thereby skip /en completely? And only have /fr for French content? They will both share the same structure for urls, like /about and /fr/about so I will need to just determine if there is a ”fr” in the beginning to make the app serve French content?

Comment: I am not saying you need to skip /en - if a user uses that, then fine - they will get the same content as if they type just /.  IMO I would support both (on the off chance the default changes later)

Regarding shared structure, now you are getting into a different design question (more than your original post).  Internationalization is its own very deep topic, but if you are only looking at messaging differences, then a single page for both languages is best.  See https://dev.to/israelmuca/tutorial-international-api---i18n--validation-in-nodejs-express-4pn1.

Comment: Thanks. I think i will stick with supporting both then.

Comment: Do you think it matters SEO wise? I mean, if I would stay with my initial plan, redirect to /en if nothing else is present in the url? In that case a 301.

Comment: I doubt it matters, but I'm not really knowledgeable about SEO.